# Pip can't find newly submitted package

Tags: python, pip

I submitted a python3 enabled version of pynliner to pip yesterday but can't seem to install it locally.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynliner3/

```
pip install pynliner3

    Updating cache with response from "https://pypi.python.org/simple/pynliner3/"
    Caching b/c date exists and max-age > 0
    Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pynliner3/
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pynliner3 (from versions: )
```

I see similar questions about this on Stackoverflow and the response always seem to be a workaround. Example "point pip directly to the tarball or repo".

However, I want to pose a different question here.

- How do I get this to work as is?
- Is this just a caching thing on pypi.python.org and I have to wait?
- If so, how long does it take?

Sorry for dumb questions. Just trying to figure out how pip works. Thanks for your help.

And for reference here's my setup.py (clone from the orignal py2 repo)

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='pynliner3',
  version='0.6',
  description='Python CSS-to-inline-styles conversion tool for HTML using'
              ' BeautifulSoup and cssutils',
  author='Tanner Netterville',
  author_email='tannern@gmail.com',
  install_requires=[
      'BeautifulSoup4 >= 4.4.1',
      'cssutils >=0.9.7',
  ],
  tests_require=[
      'mock'
  ],
  test_suite='tests',
  packages=['pynliner'],
  license='MIT',
  classifiers=[
      'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
      'Intended Audience :: Developers',
      'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
      'Topic :: Text Processing :: Markup :: HTML',
      'Programming Language :: Python',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5'
  ])
```

Comment: When I naviagated to the PyPI page for `pynliner`, I was unable to see the documentation or the wheel files - just a blank page with your name on it (presumably). Are you sure you submitted it correctly? It should appear without issue on the page if you did.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan - Any idea what I did wrong here? I used the same setup.py from my original file

Comment: [Here's](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) a reference on how to do it correctly, just in case.